# React router code splitting - events after/before load chunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

How i can get events about react router call `getComponent` and call callback with loaded component? Example of code:

```
export default (store) => ({
  path: 'somepath',
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const Container = require('./containers/Main').default
      cb(null, Container)
    }, 'module1')
  }
})
```

Obviously, i can put functions before and after `require`, but this approach is not extendable. I tryed to make proxy, like this, but get error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).ensure is not a function(…)`:

```
function requireModule(callback, moduleName) {
  return (store) => {
    // before
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      // after
      callback(require)
    }, moduleName)
  }
}


export default (store) => ({
  path: 'somepath',
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    requireModule((require) => {
      const Container = require('./containers/Main').default
      cb(null, Container)
    }, 'module1')(store)
  }
})
```

After all, i tryed to use [react-proxy-router](https://github.com/haohcraft/react-proxy-loader) and get 2 errors, but render `renderUnavailable` template. Error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `ComponentProxy`.

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `ComponentProxy`.
```

Code:

```
export default (store) => ({
  path: 'somepath',
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    var ComponentProxy = React.createClass({
        mixins: [require("react-proxy!./containers/Main").Mixin],
        renderUnavailable: function() {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }
    });

    cb(null, ComponentProxy)
  }
})
```